# First time install Django on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: django

First time ever I'm installing Django (and using python). I run Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion and by default, python is already installed:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I've followed the steps at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/install/ namely:

Download Django at https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ and run the following:

```
$ tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd Django-1.4.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

This has created a symlink in **/user/local/bin** which allows me to invoke Django from anywhere with `$ django-admin.py`

However, trying the following fails:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>
```

I should be getting something after typing `>>> import django`

```
>>> print django.get_version()
1.4
```

Is it me missing something or the documentation not so accurate?

Comment: What are expecting `import django` to do? That is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the fact that `import django` doesn't print anything means that Django was installed correctly.

`import django` only imports the Django module; it doesn't start a webserver or anything.

Comment: Ah well, then I suggest someone edits https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/install/#verifying to reflect that :-)

Comment: Actually, the documentations shows exactly what you described in your question.

Comment: @vanz: Did you type `print django.get_version()`, too?

Comment: Yes, it simply returned Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'django' is not defined