# Install Django from ZIP

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.5, and am attempting to install Django from a ZIP. I downloaded the Django ZIP and ran the installer:

```
RYAN-1970:~ jamesryan$ /Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL ; exit;
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 1: Thanks: command not found
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 3: To: command not found
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 4: this: command not found
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 10: If: command not found
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 11: site-packages: command not found
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 12: lives.: command not found
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `Unix,'
/Users/jamesryan/Downloads/django-django-597ab3c/INSTALL: line 14: `    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (Unix, Python 2.7)'
logout

[Process completed]
```

But when I try importing Django:

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

Then I tried this, based on my searches:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

First I tried using pip, but this happened:

```
>>> get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: thanks, i tried that, i posted the output.

Comment: did you do `python get-pip.py` or just `get-pip.py`?

Comment: `python: can't open file 'setup.py':` Something seems to be wrong with the folders?

Comment: @mevius i tried both.

Answer (score 1):

`INSTALL` is a set of English-language instructions describing how to install Django. It is *not* an installer. Rather than trying to execute it with a shell, read them and follow the directions inside.

As for why `get-pip.py` failed, you had a Python shell open and gave the Python prompt the filename `get-pip.py`. But the Python REPL doesn't take filenames; it takes Python expressions. It thought you were trying to retrieve the variable `get` and subtract the attribute `py` of the `pip` object. But neither `get` nor `pip` existed, so you got a `NameError`.

If you want to install pip, use a normal shell (like, say, Bash) and then run `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: Thanks icktoofay, i tried it in the shell.... RYAN-1970:~ jamesryan$ get-pip.py
-bash: get-pip.py: command not found   I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jim: You ran `get-pip.py`, not `python get-pip.py`. The `python` is required. Also make sure your current working directory (from your text, you're in your home directory) contains `get-pip.py`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: i tried....  RYAN-1970:~ jamesryan$ sudo python setup.py install
Password:
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.  i tried using the .zip file rather than the .tar.gz file.

[First time install Django on Mac OSX Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863417/first-time-install-django-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion)

thanks for your help guys, it sucks being a noob.